# Plymouth themes aren't appearing

Tags: plymouth

I use Ubuntu 16.10. Even though I choose a plymouth theme, still some codes and messages (with green "OK" in every message) are appearing while booting. I updated plymouth theme via `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth` then `sudo update-initramfs -u`.
I use Intel graphic driver

Answer (score 2):

I spent 2 days research on plymouth and coding, real fun by the way, try this.

Check your possible resolutions with `sudo hwinfo --framebuffer` and 
make following entries in `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`.

[image: grub editing]

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"


GRUB_GFXMODE="1920x1080x32"
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX="keep"
GRUB_VIDEO_BACKEND="vbe"
```

If the entries are done, run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Test splash with this command:

```
sudo plymouthd --debug  ; sudo plymouth --show-splash ; for ((I=0;I<10;I++)); do sleep 1 ; sudo plymouth --update=event$I ; done ; sudo plymouth --quit
```

If you get some splash even just Ubuntu with 4 dumb dots Plymouth is working.

Please also check the entries in your splash theme script file in this example it is ubuntu-sunrise theme, you can use following command with your path to the script file

```
sudo nano /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-sunrise/ubuntu-sunrise.script
```

There must be 2 entries like this:

[image: mytheme.script]

Insert the correct paths,

```
ImageDir=/usr/share/plymouth/themes/yourtheme

ScriptFile=/usr/share/plymouth/themes/yourtheme/yourtheme.script
```

Finally once more

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Edit ***/etc/default/grub***: you need line 9 to read:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Then run:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

NOTE: the last step is required when ever you change the plymouth theme.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo -H echo FRAMEBUFFER=y > /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash

sudo update-initramfs -u
```